# How to start Firefox with activated firebug via command line

Tags: command-line, firefox, firebug

Is there a way to activate firebug when starting Firefox via command line?

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe mysite.dev /{ACTIVATE_FIREBUG}

Comment: Just press <f12> ;)

Comment: What's the reason you want to do that?